# Changing Icon on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the icon when the audio is playing.

So, when the user hovers over the image, a `play` button will appear. The user will then click the `play` button and the audio will then begin. I'd like to icon to change to the `pause` button when the audio is playing, then when the user wants to stop the audio, they will click the `pause` button and it will return to the `play` button. I thought my code would work by removing and adding classes, but it doesn't.

```js
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");

function play() {
  icon = $(this).find("i");
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
    icon.addClass("fa-pause-circle").removeClass("fa-play-circle");
  } else {
    audio.pause();
    icon.addClass("fa-play-circle").removeClass("fa-pause-circle");
  }
}
```

```css
#credits-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 15px;
  height: 750px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10% 50px 10%;
}

#images-services {
  grid-row: span 1;
  grid-column: span 1;
}

.image-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

#coward-image:hover {
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#coward-image {
    background-image: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xQ0_zWouE8c/maxresdefault.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    transition: all .2s ease-in;
}

#coward-play {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    transition: all .2s ease-in;
}

#coward-image:hover #coward-play{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="credits">
  <div id="credits-content">
    <div id="coward-image" class="image-item images-services">
      <audio src="songs/memo.m4a" id="audio"></audio>
      <i class="far fa-play-circle fa-7x" id="coward-play" onclick="play()"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `$(this)` within the `play` function to try and reference the `i icon`, which is incorrect scope. If you wanted, you could do `onclick="play(this)"` and pass the object reference (the `i` icon element) into your `play` function and use it correctly there, using `$(thisElement)` as the object reference within the `play` function. Also, if you're using `jQuery`, you can reference the `i icon` by its id attribute of `$('#coward-play')` instead of using `.find()`; `find()` looks for nested elements...

I created an example below that shows the alternate way of using `.on('click')` functionality of `jQuery` to bind to your `coward-play icon`, but commented that code out. I've made the example use the `onclick="play(this)"` route to stay close to your original code.

I also added `onended="reset()"` to your `audio` element, so that when the audio finishes playing, it will reset the icon back to the play button as expected.

**Warning, Horse Noises when playing audio..**

```js
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");


// THIS IS AN ALTERNATE WAY OF DOING THE CLICK VIA JQUERY
/*
$('#coward-play').on('click', function() {
  play(this);
});
*/

function play(thisElement) {
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
    $(thisElement).addClass("fa-pause-circle").removeClass("fa-play-circle");
  } else {
    audio.pause();
    $(thisElement).addClass("fa-play-circle").removeClass("fa-pause-circle");
  }
}

function reset() {
  $('#coward-play').addClass("fa-play-circle").removeClass("fa-pause-circle");
}
```

```css
#credits-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 15px;
  height: 750px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10% 50px 10%;
}

#images-services {
  grid-row: span 1;
  grid-column: span 1;
}

.image-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

#coward-image:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#coward-image {
  background-image: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xQ0_zWouE8c/maxresdefault.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
}

#coward-play {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
}

#coward-image:hover #coward-play {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="credits">
  <div id="credits-content">
    <div id="coward-image" class="image-item images-services">
      <audio src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg" id="audio" onended="reset()"></audio>
      <i class="far fa-play-circle fa-7x" id="coward-play" onclick="play(this)"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `this` in your function doesn't refer to the element, as you only have access to `this` for an HTML `onclick` event inside the actual attribute.  Also, as you have the `onclick` attached to the icon itself, there is no need to use `find()`, as that method returns an element's descendant nodes.  If you move the `onclick` to the div and pass in `this` as a parameter to the function, you can use your code basically as written.  I made a Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/cblakely/pen/WBBwxK)

Comment: Perfect, thanks man. But I don't quite understand how or why I can't use the onclick event on the icon itself rather than the div?

Comment: You can, you'd just need to alter to the code to refer to the element rather find an ```i``` element in its children.  I [updated](https://codepen.io/cblakely/pen/WBBwxK) the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with some JS and JQuery.

```js
var click = 1;

function myFunction() {

  if (click < 18) {
    $('#coward-play').click(function() {

      $('#coward-play').addClass('fa-pause-circle');
      $('#coward-play').removeClass('fa-play-circle');
      click = 20;
      console.log(click);
    });
  }
  if (click > 18) {
    $('#coward-play').click(function() {
      $('#coward-play').addClass('fa-play-circle');
      $('#coward-play').removeClass('fa-pause-circle');
      click = 1;
      console.log(click);
 
    });
  }
}
```

```css
#credits-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 15px;
  height: 750px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10% 50px 10%;
}

#images-services {
  grid-row: span 1;
  grid-column: span 1;
}

.image-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

#coward-image:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#coward-image {
  background-image: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xQ0_zWouE8c/maxresdefault.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
}

#coward-play {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
}

#coward-image:hover #coward-play {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="credits">
  <div id="credits-content">
    <div id="coward-image" class="image-item images-services">
      <audio src="songs/memo.m4a" id="audio"></audio>
      <i class="far fa-play-circle fa-7x" id="coward-play" onclick="myFunction()"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```